# image loading cause UI lag and not responding

Tags: image, react-native

I have a SGListView (https://github.com/sghiassy/react-native-sglistview), which has 300 row items. Each row has an image view, and the image source is from remote network.

When I continually scroll the SGListView to the bottom, the app will enter a state that: 1) it will not show any new image view, 2) the UI begin to lag and not responding.

This state can last for seconds and later the app will recover to normal state.

It seems that the image loading action is handled one by one and previously added actions block later actions. And, the image loading process may be CPU consuming and so it causes UI lag.

So, can we cancel the image loading of some image views when needed? And how?

Comment: Have you checked the performance using ListView component of react-native? I have used ListView recently in an application which was showing remote images in item. It worked well for me. For reference please check this project https://github.com/jicksonp/TwitterSearch/blob/master/src/HomeScreen.js

Comment: Using ListView is not a choice for me, -it will exhaust memory of the phone. I'm staying on RN 0.24. I don't know whether memory usage of ListView gets fixed or not in later versions.

Comment: I see a lot of improvement in list view in react native 0.36 version.. try it out

Comment: OK, thank you, I'll try it.